# Is it good form to use an alphanumeric unique ID?

Tags: coding-style, database-design

There is a company that I am pulling data from which has a unique ID for each record. However, the ID is alphanumeric (even contains a special character too). When I asked about this I was told that this is because the leading alphanumeric portion indicates the "type" of record that it is.

Is this a proper format to use? I would have thought it would be best to just have a "type" column.

Comment: Are those prefixes stored in the database or only part of externally used IDs?

Comment: GUIDs are alphanumeric, and they have characteristics that make them very suitable for use as ID's.  That said, I'm a synthetic key zealot, so I'm against encoding information of any kind (like a "type") into an ID.  I'm a zealot about very few things (except not being a zealot), but this is one of them.

Comment: They are only part of externally used IDs on our end (the prefixes may be stored in the database on their end though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with alphanumeric IDs as such - they can be shorter, which is big advantage when they're handled by humans.

Encoding the type in the ID is certainly not good from a DB design point of view, but it can make sense as a business requirement, again for human handling.

I think the crucial point is that externally visible IDs are often subject to other requirements than only those of proper database design.